# read a text file into a binary tree but get run time error

Tags: file-io, structure, binary-search-tree

I'm having run time error in addStu function when trying to read data from input file to binary tree, is there anything wrong with the format or pointer usage?

This is my code for reading file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "BST_ADT.h"

// Structure
typedef struct
    {
        char* name;
        char* market;
        char*  initial;
        float stock;
    }STUDENT;

// Prototype Delarations
void addStu    (BST_TREE* list);
//void deleteStu (BST_TREE* list);
//void findStu   (BST_TREE* list);
//void printList (BST_TREE* list);
//int  compareStu (void* stu1, void* stu2);
//void processStu (void* dataPtr);


int main (void)
{
// Local Definitions
   BST_TREE* list;
// Statements
   list = BST_Create(compareStu);
   addStu(list);
   deleteStu(list);
   findStu (list);
   printList(list);
    return 0;
}


/*===================== addStu =========================*/

void addStu    (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Local Declarations
   STUDENT* stuPtr;
   FILE* fp;
   char fileName[25];
   char buffer [100];
// Statements

   stuPtr = (STUDENT*)malloc (sizeof (STUDENT));

   printf("Enter the file name: ");
           gets(fileName);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           if(fp == NULL)
           {
                printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
                exit(101);
           }
   while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if (!stuPtr)
                printf("MEmory overflow!\n"), exit(101);
            sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %f", stuPtr->name, stuPtr->market, stuPtr->initial, &(stuPtr->stock));;
        } // end while

   BST_Insert(list, stuPtr);
} //addStu
```

this is my input:

```
Microsoft Corporation;   NASDAQ MSFT    259.94B  
Yahoo! Inc.;         NASDAQ YHOO    37.67B  
Baidu.com, Inc. (ADR);   NASDAQ BIDU    8.64B  
CNET Networks, Inc.;     NASDAQ CNET    1.13B  
QuickLogic Corporation;  NASDAQ QUIK    88.62M  
Answers Corporation;     NASDAQ ANSW    53.49M  
Apple Inc.;              NASDAQ AAPL    114.17B  
EarthLink, Inc.;         NASDAQ ELNK    890.68M 
Amazon.com, Inc.;        NASDAQ AMZN    28.28B  
IAC/InterActiveCorp;     NASDAQ IACI    6.09B    
Time Warner Inc.;        NYSE   TWX 57.29B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent initialize the strings in your structure. Bear in mind that char* name is a POINTER to a string, NOT the string itself. Same with the other strings. In a 32 bit app, the size of char* is actually 4 bytes. That means your entire structure is 16 bytes (3 * 4 byte pointers + 1 4 byte float).

You will need to allocate space for your strings and assign them to your structure before you can try populating them from the file data. Otherwise your structure will be pointing to whatever garbage was on the heap at the pointer name* as the address of your string.

EDIT:

Try allocating some space for your strings:

stuPtr->name = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));

This will create a string large enough to hold 127 chars. Do the same for your other strings.

Comment: i did allocate the pointer to structure with this line `stuPtr = (STUDENT*)malloc (sizeof (STUDENT));`

Comment: Yes, but the pointers to the strings in the structure are not initialized. That means they will contain junk, not the address of a space where a string can exist. Try the edit mentioned above.

Comment: You will also need to allocate a new student structure for each read from the file, otherwise you will be overwriting you last structure.

Answer (score 1):

A very, very long time since I've used used C, but the fact that you are not allocating space for STUDENT elements shouts out.

When you declare 
// Structure

```
typedef struct
    {
        char* name;
        char* market;
        char*  initial;
        float stock;
    }STUDENT;
```

You are declaring space for 16 bytes (assuming 4 byte pointers and floats).

Now each of the pointers name, market and initial have undefined values when created as a STUDENT. They point to random space - if you VERY lucky they are initialised to nulls.

A better definition for STUDENT would be

```
typedef struct
    {
        char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
        char market[MAX_MARKET_SIZE];
        char  initial[MAX_INITIAL_SIZE];
        float stock;
    }STUDENT;
```

Where the MAXs are defines to be added earlier.

The other alternative would be to assign space just after creation

```
stuPtr = (STUDENT*)malloc (sizeof (STUDENT));
stuPtr->name = (char *)malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE);
stuPtr->market = (char *)malloc(MAX_MARKET_SIZE);
stuPtr->initial = (char *)malloc(MAX_INITIAL_SIZE);
```

Array names are pointers to the first element of an array, so name and &name[0] are the same.

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: I personally like this approach myself (using MAX_NAME_SIZE) as you dont need to worry about deleting the strings before you delet the structure. Of course your structure will consume more memory.